# Mongoose: returning a stored date field as timestamp (milliseconds since Unix epoch) in response

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a mongoose schema with a field `created` defined as

```
created:{ type: Date, default: Date.now }
```

so when I return this document in the api response it comes as

```
"created":"2018-04-04T19:31:38.514Z"
```

what I expect is this to return as

```
"created": 1365103898514
```

Note: I tried using virtual but it will not work as it will add a new field instead of updating the existing one. I need it to send the timestamp in the same field because we are migrating from a Java service to Nodejs service and the response types should be exactly the same as that of Java (Spring data was sending date as Unix epoch timestamp)

Comment: People are marking it as duplicate of other questions,but the solutions they are referring are related to mongodb not nodejs mongoose.